# How do I modify my Java appbundler build to sign 3rd party library

Tags: java, macos, codesign

I have added a new dependency to my Java application that includes two dynamic libs (intel/arm64 versions) and now my application is failing notarisation because

> songkong-osx.dmg/SongKong.app/Contents/Java/japlscript-executor-3.4.10.jar/japlscript-aarch64-3.4.10.dylib

in this example I am building on an M1 Mac.

```
{

    "logFormatVersion": 1,
    "jobId": "f90d1f17-d51c-4b13-95d5-3629126aa3b8",
    "status": "Invalid",
    "statusSummary": "Archive contains critical validation errors",
    "statusCode": 4000,
    "archiveFilename": "songkong-osx.dmg",
    "uploadDate": "2022-04-13T15:16:01Z",
    "sha256": "44742c010d90183f2129c675a81377f89a6321a17eaee54ecb45fa638132686c",
    "ticketContents": null,
    "issues": [
        {
            "severity": "error",
            "code": null,
            "path": "songkong-osx.dmg/SongKong.app/Contents/Java/japlscript-executor-3.4.10.jar/japlscript-x86_64-3.4.10.dylib",
            "message": "The binary is not signed.",
            "docUrl": null,
            "architecture": "x86_64"
        },
        {
            "severity": "error",
            "code": null,
            "path": "songkong-osx.dmg/SongKong.app/Contents/Java/japlscript-executor-3.4.10.jar/japlscript-x86_64-3.4.10.dylib",
            "message": "The signature does not include a secure timestamp.",
            "docUrl": null,
            "architecture": "x86_64"
        },
        {
            "severity": "error",
            "code": null,
            "path": "songkong-osx.dmg/SongKong.app/Contents/Java/japlscript-executor-3.4.10.jar/japlscript-aarch64-3.4.10.dylib",
            "message": "The binary is not signed with a valid Developer ID certificate.",
            "docUrl": null,
            "architecture": "arm64"
        },
        {
            "severity": "error",
            "code": null,
            "path": "songkong-osx.dmg/SongKong.app/Contents/Java/japlscript-executor-3.4.10.jar/japlscript-aarch64-3.4.10.dylib",
            "message": "The signature does not include a secure timestamp.",
            "docUrl": null,
            "architecture": "arm64"
        }
    ]

}
```

I have the credentials and build system to notarise my own application but I don't know how this fits in with signing the third party dynamic lib

This is the signing part of my build

```
export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate"
/usr/bin/codesign --timestamp --options runtime \
--entitlements $HOME/code/jthink/songkong/songkong.entitlements \
--sign "Developer ID Application: P Taylor" \
--force --deep --verbose /Applications/SongKong.app
/usr/bin/codesign -vvv --deep --strict /Applications/SongKong.app
spctl -a -t exec -vv /Applications/SongKong.app
cd $HOME/code/jthink/SongKong
/usr/local/bin/dmgcanvas $HOME/code/jthink/SongKong/dmgCanvas_songkong.dmgCanvas $HOME/songkong-osx.dmg -v SongKong
```

How do I modify to additionally sign this dynamic library ?

**Edit**
It seems that even though I am using `--deep` it not going deep enough ?

```
/usr/bin/codesign --timestamp --options runtime \
--entitlements $HOME/code/jthink/songkong/songkong.entitlements \
--sign "Developer ID Application: P Taylor" \
--force --deep --verbose /Applications/SongKong.app
```

and so although the verification appears ok

```
/usr/bin/codesign -vvv --deep --strict /Applications/SongKong.app
spctl -a -t exec -vv /Applications/SongKong.app
```

When it is actually sent to Apple for **notarization** (via the dmgCanvas app) it then detects these libraries and fails the notarization step.

So how do I make codesign go deeper ?

**Edit 2**

I read https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/128166 and https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/129980

and it seems that --deep doesnt always work so I added a codesign of the jar that seemed to work

```
/usr/bin/codesign --timestamp --options runtime \
--entitlements $HOME/code/jthink/songkong/songkong.entitlements \
--sign "Developer ID Application: P Taylor" \
--force --verbose /Applications/SongKong.app/Contents/Java/japlscript-executor-3.4.10.jar
```

but notarization continued to fail

One other thing I notice is there seems to be another codesign done of the dmg rather than the app just before the notarization (my DmgCanvas) could that be issue

What do I need to notarize the app or the dmg or both ?

Comment: Starting with v3.4.11, the packaged dylibs in JaplScript are already signed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sign [casamplesp](https://www.tagtraum.com/casampledsp/) libraries, I do the following:

```sh
# sign dylibs in jars
unzip -j jar_dir/casampledsp-complete* '*.dylib'
codesign -vvv -f --sign "Developer ID Application: Whatever Your Name Is" *.dylib
jar -uvf jar_dir/casampledsp-complete*  casampledsp*
rm casampledsp*
```

I.e. I extract the `*.dylib` files, sign them, and stick them back in the using the jar flags `-uvf`.

To make this work for your app, just replace `jar_dir` with the directory name of your macOS app jars.

**Added 4/20/2022:**

Starting with v3.4.11, the packaged native libs in JaplScript are already signed, so this should not be necessary anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the key thing is files cannot signed when within a jar file, but the notarization step will find them and cause notarization failure if not signed, so they have to be signed out side of jar and then put back in.

Based on Hendriks answer I extended the signing part of my build to

```
unzip -j /Applications/SongKong.app/Contents/Java/japlscript-executor-3.4.10.jar -d /Applications/SongKong.app/Contents/Java/EXTRACT
export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate"
/usr/bin/codesign --timestamp --options runtime \
--sign "Developer ID Application: P Taylor" \
--force --verbose /Applications/SongKong.app/Contents/Java/EXTRACT/*.dylib
cd /Applications/SongKong.app/Contents/Java/EXTRACT
jar -uvf /Applications/SongKong.app/Contents/Java/japlscript-executor-3.4.10.jar *.dylib
rm -fr /Applications/SongKong.app/Contents/Java/EXTRACT
cd $HOME/code/jthink/songkong
/usr/bin/codesign --timestamp --options runtime \
--entitlements $HOME/code/jthink/songkong/songkong.entitlements \
--sign "Developer ID Application: P Taylor" \
--force --deep --verbose /Applications/SongKong.app
/usr/bin/codesign -vvv --deep --strict /Applications/SongKong.app
/usr/bin/codesign -d --deep --strict /Applications/SongKong.app
spctl -a -t exec -vv /Applications/SongKong.app
cd $HOME/code/jthink/SongKong
/usr/local/bin/dmgcanvas $HOME/code/jthink/SongKong/dmgCanvas_songkong.dmgCanvas $HOME/songkong-osx.dmg -v SongKong -identity "Developer ID Application: P Taylor" -notarizationAppleID paultaylor@jthink.net -notarizationPassword xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx -notarizationPrimaryBundleID songkong
```